# Rounded linear layout leaving extra space on corners

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

i am creating a rounded linear layout with some buttons and textviews, i have used a custom selector as background of layout. My problem is that layout have extra space on corners how to remove this? any help will be appreciated
here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp"
    >
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topRightRadius="15dp"
        />
    <stroke android:width="2dip"
            android:color="@color/#275D69"/>
</shape>
```

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/selector"
    />
```

Current output: [image]

Dont want that space where i have placed red marks.

Comment: Is that linear layout contained in another layout? Post the entire XML layout file

Comment: no its the parent layout

Comment: put corner radius.

Comment: how would you fill that? if the corner is rounded you have to use another view behind or another item in the xml.. you can't round the screen :P

Comment: rounded layout won't fit to screen with corners. You will have to round your phone to remove that space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With below code you have rounded background with least space on corner

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:padding="10dp"
      android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <stroke
      android:width="2dip"
      android:color="#275D69" />
   </shape>
```

this may include space on corner but it's too low.

just reduce `radius` value.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
   <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
   <corners
      android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
      android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
      android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
      android:topRightRadius="15dp" />
   <stroke android:width="0dip"
    android:color="@color/#275D69"/>
</shape>
<corners android:radius="6dip" />
```

Put `corner radius` whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution you need to follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">

      <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
          <corners
            android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
            android:topRightRadius="15dp" />

      <stroke
            android:width="2dip"
            android:color="#275D69"/>

 </shape>
```

Now in main xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical">

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"
        android:orientation="vertical">
   </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this approach, is not the most clear solution but for me works:

Create a Layout container with transparent background, and use it as a container of your rounded layout

```
<LinearLayout
.....
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
......>

  <LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/selector"
    android:orientation="vertical">

     <!-- content of the rounded ll -->
   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The white spaces should be disappeared

Answer (score 0):

> You can make rounded corners using cardView

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
app:cardBackgroundColor="#D3D3D3"
app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="3dp" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

After getting pissed for 2 days I finally found it .
It cannot be solved by any drawable files or by editing the canvas but simply by making the layout as base layout.

There are several methods and stuffs under values you have to choose the right ones and add it in your styles.

First add these to your styles.xml

```
<style name="AppBottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/CustomBottomSheetStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomBottomSheetStyle" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/drawable_round_bottom_sheet</item>
</style>
```

Now the most important part is to call the AppBottomDialogue for this I used this

```
 override fun getTheme(): Int {
    return R.style.AppBottomSheetDialogTheme
}
```

Now you can choose whatever to do with your method I used ImagesView inside ConstraintLayout you can directly clip it no problem.